# Convert GPS message content into just latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, gps, latitude-longitude

How can I convert this GPS message content "lat:14.674513 long:120.549137 
speed:8.95 
T:13/09/24 20:27 
bat:50% 
 http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=14.674513,120.549137&z=16 " from a database into just value of latitude and longitude to be able to plot this coordinates in map?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$gps = 'lat:14.674513 long:120.549137 speed:8.95 T:13/09/24 20:27 bat:50%';
preg_match('/lat:(\d+\.\d+) long:(\d+\.\d+)/', $gps, $matches);
unset($matches[0]);
$params = array(
    'f' => 'q',
    'q' => implode(',', $matches),
    'z' => 16,
);
$query = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?' . http_build_query($params);
```